# What is the duty of the main thread in a C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I can not find anything about it on the google

So what happens when we throttle the main thread?

Let's say I have started 3 background threads separate from the main thread

They continue to run as expected

But do they get affected when the main thread is throttled?

Assume that there are enough system resources of the separate threads

Comment: What have you found? Did you actually code a small app to demonstrate it? That aside, when you throttle the main thread, you will seize up the UI,other threads will run independently as they are in different context.

Comment: This question is far too broad. The behavior will depend on how exactly the threads relate to each other, if at all. In WPF, or any other framework, background threads often need to interact with the "primary" thread (e.g. a dispatcher thread in WPF). Contention, computations, or other things that may cause the primary thread to slow or wait may affect other threads, as they interact with that thread.

Comment: There actually is a _lot_ on Google, MSDN, Stack Overflow, etc. regarding how threads work. That would be the place for you to start. If you get to a point where you have a good [mcve] that you're having trouble understanding, or getting to work as you want, then you should feel free to post that along with a precise, _specific_ question about that MCVE.

Comment: @PeterDuniho actually i wonder that does main thread have a duty like being an organizer, a boss? like global variables handling etc? actually this dispatcher thread gives me hint. since there has to be new tasks spawned, i guess it is done by the main thread even if spawned in another thread right?

Comment: Variables are data. They are associated with threads only if you implement that explicitly; there's no inherent correlation. And new threads can be started by any other thread. As I said, to fully educate you on the topic, as you seem to want, is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question. You should do research for that type of question, and limit Stack Overflow to things that are on-topic (i.e. _specific_, practical questions related to programming).

Answer (score 0):

Throttling the main thread should do nothing to the threads that it has spawned.  It's my understanding that threads really know nothing about other threads (besides the occasional wait or start of another thread).  They essentially run independently of each other but they do share common resource such as virtual address space and system resources because those are given out by the operating system to a specific process.  If a process is "throttled" or lowered in priority by the operating system than yes all of the threads that belong to that process will also be throttled or lowered in priority.

See [About Processes And Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: i checked there but i can not find duty of the primary - main thread